# Optimizar INSERT EXEC con WHILE

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

estoy generando una data la cual me esta tardando mucho tiempo en generar y quisiera ver de que forma puedo optimizarlo

tengo la siguiente tabla

```
SELECT 
 Number
,NumberCredit
FROM dbo.CreditTotal
```

que unicamente es una lista de numeros de credito con su respectivo numero de orden, en total son alrededor de 53,000 registros

```
Number           NumberCredit
1                  234324224
2                  985739932
3                  134902488
4                  342509583
5                  194772838
```

la info que quiero me la genera un procedimiento almacenado que se ejecuta con un solo parametro el cual es el NumberCredit de la tabla de arriba, para lo cual he creado un ciclo while para que me vaya ejecutando ese SP por cada credito, el SP tarda 0 segundos en ejecutar ese es rapido

comparto script

```
--Creo tabla que va a ir insertando informacion resultante del SP dentro del ciclo

CREATE TABLE dbo.GarantiaRec(
 [Nº] INT 
,[Fecha] DATETIME
,[GarantiaReciprocaSet] NUMERIC(18,2)
,[NumberCredit] VARCHAR(30)
)

CREATE INDEX idx_NumberCredit ON dbo.GarantiaRec(NumberCredit)
CREATE INDEX idx_Fecha ON dbo.GarantiaRec(Fecha)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------


DECLARE @Loop INT = 1
DECLARE @nRegistros INT = (SELECT COUNT(t.NumberCredit) FROM dbo.CreditTotal t)


WHILE(@nRegistros>0 AND @Loop<=@nRegistros)
BEGIN

DECLARE @NumberCredito VARCHAR(30) = (SELECT t.NumberCredit FROM dbo.CreditTotal t WHERE t.Number = @Loop )

INSERT INTO dbo.GarantiaRec
EXEC Garantia_reciproca @NumberCredito

SET @Loop = @Loop +1

END
```

El script funciona perfecto, sin embargo tarda alrededor de 4 horas en insertar todo

¿Es posible optimizarlo para que tarde menos tiempo?

Comment: Saludos. Vi que definiste la tabla donde estas realizando las inserciones pero no la tabla de donde estas leyendo los registros. Pregunto, la tabla CreditTotal posee clave primaria e índices? Provee la mayor cantidad de información posible para que los miembros de la comunidad podamos ayudarte con mas facilidad.

Comment: La tabla CreditTotal  tiene indice en NumberCredit

Comment: Necesitas compartir el código de `Garantia_reciproca` para poder optimizar el código.

Comment: Sin saber lo que hace el procedimiento almacenado, no queda de otra que lanzarlo todas las veces. Lo que si puedes evitar es ir insertando en `GarantiaRec` uno por uno y hacer una inserción masiva, pero el impacto en el tiempo de ejecución total de 4 horas es mínimo. Otra opción sería ejecutar este proceso en paralelo desde un lenguaje de más alto nivel, pero cuánto mejore el rendimiento en este caso depende de los recursos de hardware a disposición del servidor.

Answer (score -1):

En lugar de ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado para cada registro de forma individual, puede **procesarlos en lotes**. Por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 1000
DECLARE @Offset INT = 0
DECLARE @TotalRecords INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.CreditTotal)

WHILE (@Offset < @TotalRecords)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.GarantiaRec
    EXEC Garantia_reciproca_batch @BatchSize, @Offset
    
    SET @Offset += @BatchSize
END
```

Comment: Me genera error " Could not find stored procedure 'Garantia_reciproca_batch'. " ya que no es el nombre del SP, ¿habria que hacer modificacion al mismo?